# How do I dynamically create an XML schema in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

I try to dynamically create an XML schema (XSD) from C#, using the conventional XElement and XAttribute classes, but it is not valid to specify any names with colons. That is, I cannot create the element <xs:element> using the code

```
... = new XElement("xs:element");
```

because ":" is not allowed.

What is the correct way of dynamically building a schema in C# then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating new XML elements, you should be aware that the part before the colon (in this case, `xs`) is actually an alias for the XML namespace (in the case of an XSD, `xs` usually refers to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`).  So, to continue using XDocument to build your XSD, you would want to use:

```
XNamespace ns = new XNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
... = new XElement(ns + "element");
```

See the example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292758.aspx

Comment: But that would give me an element that looks like <element xmlns="http://www..."> instead of <xs:element> ...

Comment: It does mean, semantically, the same thing.  If you want the abbreviation, I believe you can add the definitions as Marc specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265378/how-do-i-add-multiple-namespace-declarations-to-an-xdocument, though I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Thanks! together with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338517/how-can-i-write-xml-with-a-namespace-and-prefix-with-xelement this answered my question! :-)

Answer (score 2):

To create schemas, you should be using the XmlSchema class. The link below provides a comprehensive example of creating one programmatically:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ta3w88s.aspx

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var schema = new XmlSchema();

    // <xs:element name="myElement" type="xs:string"/>
    var myElement = new XmlSchemaElement();
    schema.Items.Add(myElement);
    elementCat.Name = "myElement";
    elementCat.SchemaTypeName = 
        new XmlQualifiedName("string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

    // writing it out to any stream
    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    schema.Write(Console.Out, nsmgr);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: @John: Good point. The comprehensive example does show it, but I will update the code right now.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/01/05/create-an-xsd-schema-without-knowing-a-damn-thing-about-xsd.aspx) about that very subject.  You can use a DataTable to save a schema.

Comment: I would really like to create it explicitly (instead of through intermediate data structures) to gain full control. I would be able to do this using XElement and XAttribute if just they allowed ":" in the names.

Comment: -1: @Steve, aren't there a few restrictions if you use a `DataTable`? Like, you could only create XML schema that maps to a relational model?

Comment: @John, Sure there are restrictions.  It creates schemas that describe XML structures that can be read in by DataTables.  Depending on your needs, that's either a benefit or a drawback.

Comment: @John...the big benefit is that you don't have to learn the schema language.

Comment: if the OP had said he was interested in restricting to "relational" data, then I wouldn't have downvoted. The absence of any constraints made my downvote an answer which places constraints on the schema which can be produced.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create xml, you should use XmlWriter class

Comment: I mean that xsd schema is an xml. XmlWriter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx has all the methods to create custom xml

Comment: did you know that `XmlDocument` or LINQ to XML can also be used to create "custom XML", and a lot more easily that using `XmlWriter` directly?

Comment: @John Saunders: No i didnt. I think `XmlDocument` or is better when manipulating with existing xml, as they support navigating and editing too. As from MSDN  - "`XmlWriter` Represents a writer that provides a fast, non-cached, forward-only means of generating streams or files containing XML data.". You're right - LINQ to Xml is simpler to use, but isn't in built on top of `XmlWriter`?

Comment: yes, it's built on XmlWriter, which makes it much easier to use than XmlWriter. And I didn't say "better than", I said "also". Both XmlDocument and LINQ to XML are much easier to use for this purpose that a raw XmlWriter.